# Problems with fwrite

Tags: c++, file-io, fwrite, mergesort

I'm doing an external merge sort for an assignment and I'm given two structs:

```
    // This is the definition of a record of the input file. Contains three fields, recid, num and str
typedef struct {
    unsigned int recid;
    unsigned int num;
    char str[STR_LENGTH];
    bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
    int blockID; //The block the record belongs too -> Used only for minheap
} record_t;


// This is the definition of a block, which contains a number of fixed-sized records
typedef struct {
    unsigned int blockid;
    unsigned int nreserved; // how many reserved entries
    record_t entries[MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK]; // array of records
    bool valid;  // if set, then this block is valid
    unsigned char misc;
    unsigned int next_blockid;
    unsigned int dummy;
} block_t;
```

Also I'm given this:

```
void MergeSort (char *infile, unsigned char field, block_t *buffer,
            unsigned int nmem_blocks, char *outfile,
            unsigned int *nsorted_segs, unsigned int *npasses,
            unsigned int *nios)
```

Now, at phase 0 I'm allocating memory like this:

```
buffer = (block_t *) malloc (sizeof(block_t)*nmem_blocks);
//Allocate disc space for records in buffer
record_t *records = (record_t*)malloc(nmem_blocks*MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK*sizeof(record_t));
```

And then after I read the records from a binary file (runs smoothly), I write them to multiple files (after sorting of course and some other steps) with this command:

```
outputfile = fopen(name.c_str(), "wb");
fwrite(records, recordsIndex, sizeof(record_t), outputfile);
```

and read like this:

```
fread(&buffer[b].entries[rec],sizeof(record_t),1,currentFiles[b])
```

And it works! Then I want to combine some of these files to produce a larger sorted file using a priority_queue turned to minheap (it's tested, it works), but when I try to write to files using this command:

```
outputfile = fopen(outputName.c_str(), "ab"); //Opens file for appending
fwrite(&buffer[nmem_blocks-1].entries, buffer[nmem_blocks-1].
                           nreserved, sizeof(record_t), outputfile);
```

It writes nonsense in the file, as if it reads random parts of memory.

I know that the code is probably not nearly enough, but all of it is quite large. 
I'm making sure I'm closing the output file before I open it again using a new name. Also I use `memset()` (and not `free()`) to clear the buffer before I fill it again.

Comment: You have to choose: C or C++? Based on the functions called, I am assuming this is C, and updating tags accordingly.

Comment: `&buffer[nmem_blocks-1].entries` should be `buffer[nmem_blocks-1].entries`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Still it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: As usual: do not cast malloc return, please.

Comment: @LPs Then it gives a compilation error for invalid conversion from void* to block_t* 
You mean something different?

Comment: @Sofia I thought your code was C not C++. Why are using malloc in C++?

Comment: @LPs Proffesor's guidelines. If it was up to me, I'd use new.

Comment: If your professor wants you to use `malloc` instead of `new` in C++ they're a jackass.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It wasn't necessary, but since we wrote it this way I kept it.

Comment: You are using buffer[nmem_blocks-1].entries to write a buffer that is loaded by number of files. Are those indexes correlated?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: You load with `fread` from `N` files (index `b`), but on the second `fwrite` you use a fixed index `nmem_blocks-1`. Is it correct? Or shall be `buffer[0].entries` where `nreserved` is the number of records loaded into buffer struct?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct, because I basically want to write to file only the last block of the buffer that contains the output and then reload it.

Comment: I think we need more code to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the main problem was the way I was trying to open the file:

```
outputfile = fopen(outputName.c_str(), "ab"); //Opens file for appending
```

Instead I should have used again:

```
outputfile = fopen(outputName.c_str(), "wb"); //Opens file for writing to end of file
```

Because the file in the meantime never closed, so it was trying to open an already open file for appending and it didn't work quite well. But you couldn't have known since you didn't have the full code. Thank you for your help though! :)